# Normalizar database (unpivot colunas por mês)

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel

Boa noite,

Uma tabela em Excel com ligação SQL da PERVASIVE com uma coluna por mês, ou seja, 12 colunas.
De forma a melhor trabalhar os dados, necessito de transformar as 12 colunas em somente 2:
 - uma 1ª com os valores que estavam nas 12 colunas
 - uma 2ª coluna com o respetivo mês, ou seja, o que era antes do título das colunas.

Tabela atual:

```
Al_Cta     | MoedCod | TpVal   | FlagDC  | Month01 | Month02 | Month03
AAAAA      |     100 |      20 |        5|      15 |      18 |      16
BBBBB      |     200 |      40 |       10|      20 |      21 |      26
CCCCC      |     300 |      60 |       15|      40 |      48 |      41
```

E quero:

```
Al_Cta     |  MoedCod|TpVal | FlagDC  | Value   | Month
AAAAA      |     100 |    20|       5 |      15 |     01
AAAAA      |     100 |    20|       5 |      18 |     02
AAAAA      |     100 |    20|       5 |      16 |     03
BBBBB      |     200 |    40|      10 |      20 |     01
BBBBB      |     200 |    40|      10 |      21 |     02
BBBBB      |     200 |    40|      10 |      26 |     03
CCCCC      |     300 |    60|      15 |      40 |     01
CCCCC      |     300 |    60|      15 |      48 |     02
CCCCC      |     300 |    60|      15 |      41 |     03
```

Obrigado

Comment: você precisa de uma macro para gerar outra planilha "normalizada"?

Comment: https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Transformar-colunas-Power-Query-em-linhas-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098